# How do I keep my character's clothes from slipping?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make jeans for my character, and they're meant to be skinny jeans so I want them to be tight around the waist. But every time I've tried the pants keep sliding down the legs. What can I do to fix this?[image]

Comment: Maybe remove gravity, let the simulation run for a bit, bake the shape, PIN the top of the pants, add gravity and cloth simulation back?

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to not make it a cloth simulation, just parent it to the armature and then copy the character weights with the data transfer modifier on top of the armature modifier with these settings

in source select the mesh that you want to copy from

[image]

then just generate data layers and apply

Comment: Meaning don't do sewing and all that? Just model the pants and give it that data transfer modifier?